# How to define custom function like StringBuilder.Appand() on C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, function, methods

I want to make same function who passing two parameters like this

```
myClass mc=new myClass();
mc.values("string_col1","string_val1");
mc.values("string_col2","string_val2");
```

I am making separate class for insert value in database through store procedure, my function is

```
public void sp_insert(string pro_name, string pro_val)
    {
        cnnction.Open();
        cm.CommandText = pro_name;
        cm.Connection = cnnction;
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string[] name = pro_val.Split('|');
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] var = name[i].Split(',');
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(var[0], var[1]);
        }
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnnction.Close();
    }`
```

Now when I call this method I want this

```
sp_insert("procedure_name",mc);
```

previous am work like this

```
sp_insert("procedure_name","@col1,value1|@col2,value2")
```

I know this is worst work some @ or | plz any help

Comment: you could just use a `Dictionary<T, T2>`...

Comment: Please clarify your question. Currently I couldn't understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Daniel said, you can use `Dictionary` for this.

Change `sp_insert` method to be like :

```
public void sp_insert(string pro_name, Dictionary<string,string> pro_val)
{
    cnnction.Open();
    cm.CommandText = pro_name;
    cm.Connection = cnnction;
    cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    foreach (var item in pro_val)
    {
       cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnnction.Close();
}
```

And in wherever place you called this method, pass this dictionary to it

```
Dictionary<string,string> var = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var.Add("@param1","paramValue1");
var.Add("@param2", "paramValue2");
```

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel and @MartinSiagian. it work nicely and perfect guys also look my other question
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271996/how-to-use-asp-net-web-service-3-5-soap-on-android-windows-phone-8-apps-or-win)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the params keyword: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

```
public void sp_insert(string pro_name, params string[] pro_val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pro_val.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(pro_val[i] + " ");
    }
   `enter code here`[...]
}
```

And you might also wanna create a class for wrapping these values:

```
public class ColValueWrap
{
   public string Col { get; set;}
   public string Val { get; set; }

   public ColValueWrap(string col, string val) 
   {
      Col = col;
      Val = val;
   }
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
public void sp_insert(string pro_name, params ColValueWrap[] pro_vals)
{
   foreach (var val in pro_vals)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(val.Col + ":" + val.Val);
   }
   `enter more code here`[...]
}

sp_insert("procedure_name",new ColValueWrap("@col1", "val1"), new ColValueWrap("@col2", "val2"));
```